# Donut Chart : Trigger legend or pie click event while selecting outside filter state change

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, chart.js, donut-chart, recharts

Please see this screenshot

[image: scrnshot]

1. When I click on legend item, the pie will be highlighted or selected in react js
2. but when I trigger legend click from custom filter state, the pie is not getting selected

Can someone please share any solution for react js to trigger legend and pie chart selection from an outside filter?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please share some code that shows us what you've tried so far? That would make helping you find your issue significantly easier

Comment: I'm triggering click event on componentDidUpdate : 
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {  
  if (selectedSeriesIndex !== prevProps.selectedSeriesIndex) {
    $('.apexcharts-legend-series').removeClass('active');
    $('.apexcharts-legend-series[rel = ' + (selectedSeriesIndex + 1) + ']').addClass('active');
    $('.apexcharts-legend-series[rel = ' + (selectedSeriesIndex + 1) + '].active').trigger('click');
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setVisible` method on a series related to a specific button:

```
handleClick(e) {
  const series = this.internalChart.series;

  series[e.currentTarget.attributes.index.value].setVisible();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={this.state.chartOptions}
        callback={this.afterChartCreated}
      />
      <h2>custom legend</h2>
      <div>Series 1
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          index="0"
          onChange={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          defaultChecked={true}
        />
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/91opxqwn1r

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the update, I resolved the issue by using recharts.